# How Or where Do I access my properties file

Tags: java, spring

I have a properties file myprops.properties as follows:

```
Wsdl=someurl
UserName=user
UserPassword=pasword
Application=appName
```

And inside my controller I'm trying to access to set values in my service as follows

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("resources/myprops.properties"));
myService.setWsdl(prop.getProperty("Wsdl"));
myService.setUserName(prop.getProperty("UserName"));
myService.setUserPassword(prop.getProperty("UserPassword"));
myService.setApplication(prop.getProperty("Application"));
```

my Issue is I just do not know what path to use. Its a Spring project if that makes any difference. and Idealy I would like to have the properties file in my "src/main/resources" folder

I realise this may be very simple to some but I have tried searching for the solution both here and on Google and I cannot seem to find a solution that has helped. I've tried moving the file around the project but cannot seem to figure it out

The Error I get is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\drm.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

any advice/explanation or even a link that clearly explains it would be great

Comment: Your properties file contains invalid syntax.

Comment: Your properties file should be like `Wsdl=someurl`

Comment: Lack of research?  I found several answers in SO in a few minutes.

Comment: @Jessemon I found answers to similar issues but none that worked for me or explained in a way I could understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spring, you could set your property placeholder.

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/myprops.properties" />
```

and in your beans you can inject the values from the properteis using the `@Value` annotation

```
@Autowired
public Foo(@Value("${Wsdl}") String wsdl) {
   ...
}
```

in the case above I used in the constructor, but its possible to use by Autowired field/setter.

So in your service you could have something like:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
     private final String wsdl;
     private final String username;
     private final String password;
     private final String application;

     @Autowired
     public MyService(
         @Value("${Wsdl}") String wsdl,
         @Value("${UserName}") String username,
         @Value("${UserPassword}") String password,
         @Value("${Application}") String application
         ) {
         // set it to each field.
     }
}
```

Comment: This took me a while to figure out but now that I have Definitely worth it and much more suitable then Reimeus example, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

well, src/main/resources are on the classpath, you just need to do.

Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("your properties file name");

Answer (score 1):

Given that `src/main/resources` is on the classpath, you could do:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/myprops.properties");
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

Comment: I still get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [myprops.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `FileInputStream`; use `getResourceAsStream()` to read it from the servlet context.

Comment: I tried this and get `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine`

Comment: You didn't check to see if the InputStream that you got back was null.  Could be that the path you gave it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can always count on mkyong.  This is an example/tutorial on how to load and read property files.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

This question should be marked as a duplicate:

1. [Loading a properties file from Java package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333363/loading-a-properties-file-from-java-package/333385#333385)
2. [How to use Java property files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files)
3. [Load a property file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207790/load-a-property-file-in-java)
4. [Java Properties File not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777252/java-properties-file-not-loading)
5. [Java NullPointerException on loading properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838988/java-nullpointerexception-on-loading-properties-file)
6. [Not able to load properties file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596155/not-able-to-load-properties-file-in-java)